# How to iterate over an array in rails activeadmin CSV?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, activeadmin

I was trying to create a custom CSV in active admin for Saloon model and I have one column with an array of OperationalHours.

Here is my Object:

```
[20] pry(main)> Saloon.first
=> #<Saloon:0x00007fa773496cf0
 id: 1,
 address_1: "1313 2nd St South",
 city: "Battlefield",
 state: "Missouri",
 zip: "63303",
 operational_hours:
  [#<OperationalHours:0x00007fa77aa72848 @closing_time="5:00 PM", @notes="", @opening_time="9:00 AM">,
   #<OperationalHours:0x00007fa77aa725f0 @closing_time="5:00 PM", @notes="", @opening_time="9:00 AM">,
   #<OperationalHours:0x00007fa77aa723c0 @closing_time="5:00 PM", @notes="", @opening_time="9:00 AM">,
   #<OperationalHours:0x00007fa77aa72190 @closing_time="Closed", @notes="", @opening_time="Closed">,
   #<OperationalHours:0x00007fa77aa71f10 @closing_time="Closed", @notes="", @opening_time="Closed">,
   #<OperationalHours:0x00007fa77aa71ce0 @closing_time="Closed", @notes="", @opening_time="Closed">,
   #<OperationalHours:0x00007fa77aa71ab0 @closing_time="Closed", @notes="", @opening_time="Closed">],
 name: "Clear Cut",
 trial_period: 30,
 time_zone: "Central Time (US & Canada)">
```

And in my active admin file I have:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Saloon do
  csv do 
    column :name 
    column "Operation Hours" do |sal|
     sal.operational_hours.each do |hour|
      "#{hour.opening_time}-#{hour.closing_time}"
     end
    end
  end
end
```

But operational hours on CVS has:

```
[#<OperationalHours:0x00007fcf295e2a90 @opening_time="9:00 AM", @closing_time="5:00 PM", @notes="">,
 #<OperationalHours:0x00007fcf295e2798 @opening_time="9:00 AM", @closing_time="5:00 PM", @notes="">,
 #<OperationalHours:0x00007fcf295e2428 @opening_time="9:00 AM", @closing_time="5:00 PM", @notes="">,
 #<OperationalHours:0x00007fcf295e2158 @opening_time="9:00 AM", @closing_time="5:00 PM", @notes="">,
 #<OperationalHours:0x00007fcf295e1eb0 @opening_time="9:00 AM", @closing_time="5:00 PM", @notes="">,
 #<OperationalHours:0x00007fcf295e1910 @opening_time="9:00 AM", @closing_time="5:00 PM", @notes="">,
 #<OperationalHours:0x00007fcf295e1690 @opening_time="9:00 AM", @closing_time="5:00 PM", @notes="">]
```

Is there a way to iterate over operational hours and show each as "9:00 AM-5:00 PM"format?

Comment: Your "CSV" sample isn't a CSV format.

Comment: @theTinMan I followed https://activeadmin.info/4-csv-format.html documentation. I am getting CSV too. But the problem is my operational hours is not being formatted as I wanted.

Comment: What does operation_hours.keys give you? Try that and also as `hour[@opening_time]` and `hour[@closing_time]`

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking wrong all along. For solution, I made a method on the Saloon model to send formatted operational hours.

```
  def sanitized_operational_hours
    hours = ""
    self.operational_hours.each_with_index do |v, i|
      if i==6
        hours += "#{Date::DAYNAMES[0]} #{v.opening_time} - #{v.closing_time} "
      else 
        hours += "#{Date::DAYNAMES[i+1]} #{v.opening_time} - #{v.closing_time} "
      end
    end
    hours
  end
```

And on my active admin I called this method

```
  column "Operational Hours" do |t|
      t.sanitized_operational_hours
  end
```